# Show first two digits of time that is over 24 hours

Tags: excel, date, hour

In EXCEL I have cells showing the total time of operations in `HH:MM` (rather than `DD/MM/YYY HH:MM`). I have formatted the cell so that instead of DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM, it shows the total hours (e.g. 01 day and 13 hours would show 37:00). So for example I am simply trying to show '37' in a different cell.

Comment: What are you doing this in? Excel? Including some examples would be good as well.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? It kind of sounds like you are not grasping the concept of time here - sounds a bit silly - but obviously if you reach 24 hours, you'll just reach the next day and start counting a new (basically a circle with `360 degrees == 0`) How do you want to differentiate between what you want to add? Because the fact it's 02:00 and 18:00 are two vastly different values in which it makes very little sense to actually add them up together. Usually you need some start time and end time and aim to track the difference between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use =TEXT(Reference cell,"hh") along with your formula to find

Answer (score 0):

If the date is in text form, `=MID(A1,1,FIND(":",A1)-1)` should work.

+------[edit]-----+

Use

```
=INT(VALUE(A1))*24+HOUR(A1)
```

Comment: it doesn't / won't. `=FIND()` can only be applied to strings ("Text" cells). The time inside his cell is of different format and hence will always return `#VALUE!` error. Try it yourself and you'll see. Obviously, you can convert it to string, but as OP specified, it's in time format and as of now it's not incorporated in your answer

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've tried to put more than 24 hours in `hh:mm` format, it automatically saved as text instead of `hh:mm` format. Appreciate @Eric Snodgrass can share how to generate the >24 hrs 'hh:mm cell to proceed. (: